Proof that elementary row operations preserve column rank
I'm following along Jim Hefferon's Linear Algebra. So far, the theory that row rank = column rank isn't proven. Additionally, invertibility of a matrix hasn't been defined. So, without using these laws, the author had to show that an elementary row operation preserves column rank.
The proof in the textbook relies on the following statement: "This proof will be finished if we show that row operations do not affect linear relationships among columns, because the column rank is the size of the largest set of unrelated columns". But this feels like a very qualitative reasoning and I personally can't see how not affecting the linear relationship of the columns preserves the dimension of the column space.
If this statement is accepted, the proof that follows is simple. Consider the following equation $c_1\vec{\alpha}_1 + ... + c_n\vec{\alpha}_n = \vec{0}$ where $\vec{\alpha}_1,...,\vec{\alpha}_n$ are the columns of a matrix. After a row operation, the columns may change but the solution set is the same. Thus, the values of $c_1,...,c_n$ are preserved. So, $c_1\vec{\alpha}_1' + ... + c_n\vec{\alpha}_n' = \vec{0}$.
I'm trying a different, more quantitative approach. Firstly, suppose that the given matrix has linearly independent columns. Then, the only solution to the equation $c_1\vec{\alpha}_1 + ... + c_n\vec{\alpha}_n = \vec{0}$ is the trivial one. Since the solution set is preserved, the zero values of $c_1,...,c_n$ are preserved after a row operation: $c_1\vec{\alpha}_1' + ... + c_n\vec{\alpha}_n' = \vec{0}$. So, the dimension of the new matrix's column space remains as $n$. So, the column rank is preserved.
Now, my question is the following: how can I handle the case where the matrix contains linearly dependent columns?

You want to show that the "relations" between the columns remains unchanged, that is, if $c_1\vec{\alpha}_1 + ... + c_n\vec{\alpha}_m = \vec{0}$ will hold for the column vectors $\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_m$ iff it used to hold earlier. You could also say that you want to show that these maps of row transformations on the set of columns or rather the set of all $n$ tuples is infective, and so also subjective. Thus, we only need to show that these maps are all isomorphisms, and then the final column space will be isomorphic to the original column space and so their dimension/column rank is preserved.
For each of the elementary row operations:

Multiplying a row $i$ by a non-zero scalar $\lambda$:

This is same as for every column $(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_i,\dots, x_n)$, we replace it with $(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_{i-1}, \lambda x_i, x_{i+1},\dots, x_n)$. Surely this is an isomorphism and I will not be proving that here.

Swapping two rows $i<j$:

This is same as the isomorphism that takes a column $(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ to $(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1}, x_j, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_{j-1}, x_i, \dots, x_n )$. Again proving that this is an isomorphism is not too hard.
You can try to do a similar argument for the third operation as well to show that it is an isomorphism to finish from here.
